Sorting non-padded lines
A list of non-zero-padded unsorted lines is given:
seq 100 | shuf

piping that into sort would give:
1
10
100
11
12
13
...

because sort sorts lexicographical by default. Thus, it has -n option for numerical sort, which would yield the expected result. However, if strings are not totally numeric, this wouldn't work:
seq 100 | shuf | sed s/^/E/ | sort -n

Or for a more complex case:
paste -dS <(seq 100 | shuf | sed 's/^/E/' | sort -n) <(seq 100 | shuf)
---
E1S70
E10S75
E100S41
E11S53
...

with the expected output of lexicographical sorting for characters but numerical sorting for numbers:
E1S70
E10S75
E11S53
E100S41

Think of numbers as a single block, compared numerically with other numbers, but lexicographically with other characters.
What's an efficient way to sort non-zero-padded mixed strings?

it's not clear (to me) what the expected output is to be for the 4-line E* dataset; it's also not clear how you'd expect to sort E10S33 / ES204F3 / B27Y23S1 / YF29399G3G3G (or if this is a valid data set); please update the question with 3-4 different, sorted data sets (4-5 lines each)

without more examples and a clear(er) explanation I'm going to guess sort -V (or sort --version-sort) may be what you want

That would be a GNU extension yes? the sort -v or --version-sort

Updated. Another way to view this is that all numbers are padded then lexicographically sorted, then unpadded. That's the expected output. Which is why I asked the 2nd question of whether there is a way to pad/unpad strings mixed with numbers.

Yes, something like sort -V is what I'm looking for, but unfortunately it doesn't work for the complex case. Why?

When in doubt, reach for a Schwartzian transform. In this case, decorate with the numbers and then letters with a distinct column delimiter, sort, then undecorate.

how does sort -V misorder your "complex case"? I get a list of 100 strings, sorted from E1... up to E100..., which seems exactly what you specified as desired output

My bad. sort -V seems to be the solution I'm looking for. Any thoughts on my 2nd question? I think @dawg's answer can be modified to zero-pad the numbers. I moved it to a separate post to keep this one focused: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78846515

You appear to be describing natural sort:

natural sort order (or natural sorting) is the ordering of strings in alphabetical order, except that multi-digit numbers are treated atomically, i.e., as if they were a single character

It is not clear how you wish to handle fractional numbers (could be delimited with various characters such as . or ,); or a mix of zero-padded and non-padded numbers.

For shell programming, GNU has extended sort with a -V/--version-sort option, although this may not do what you want for a list such as:
B27Y23S1
E10S33
ES020.4F3
ES20.14F3
ES2014F3
YF29399G3G3G

Perl has Sort::Versions, Sort::Key::Natural, etc.
(cf. Perl sort numbers naturally)
Python has natsort, etc.
(cf. Is there a built in function for string natural sort?)
Javascript has natural-sortby, etc.
(cf. Natural sort of alphanumerical strings in JavaScript)
I expect other environments have also come up with their own solutions.

Given:
$ cat file
E1S70
E10S75
E100S41
E11S53

You can do something along these lines:
awk '{
        s=t=$0
        gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"\t", s)
        gsub(/[0-9]+/,"\t",t)   
        $0=sprintf("%s\t%s\t%s",s,t,$0)
    }1' file | sort -n | awk '{print $NF}'

Prints:
E1S70
E10S75
E11S53
E100S41

This uses a Decorate, Sort, Undecorate idiom to add columns to separate out the items you wish to use to sort; in this case, numerals and then letters.

this code seems to misorder the sample input in my answer (B27... should precede E...), and (arguably) ES020.4F3 should come after ES20.14F3)

maybe: awk '{s=$0; gsub(/[0-9]+/," & ",s); print s,$0}' file|... ? Still has gotchas if lines don't always have the same number of parts
