Zero-pad numbers within a string
Original question: Sorting non-padded lines
Given a non-zero-padded mixed string, how to zero-pad it up to the number of digits of the longest number?
Example input:
S70E1
S75E10
S41E100
S53E11

Example output:
S070E001
S075E010
S041E100
S053E011

Mixed strings can have any number of characters and numbers. E.g:
Season1Episode3 or Seas3Epi5. Non-digit strings don't need to be padded.

how large is the input? Is it a file (ie. seekable) or streamed?

It should be assumed that it's not streamed, since introducing a line with a bigger number would change the number of zeroes to pad.

Are the non-digit parts always single letters or could you have a string like ABC27DEFGH123 in the input? If so, do the non-digit strings need to be padded in any way? Are the non-digit parts ALWAYS a leading S and then a single E in the middle of the digits or could there be other letters and/or other than 2 non-digits in a line? Are there always exactly 2 digits between S and E or could there be 1, 3, etc.?

Please [edit] your question to answer those questions and update your sample input/output to cover all possible use cases if your input isn't always an S followed by 2 digits followed by an E then up to 3 digits as currently shown.

these look like (TV show) season/episode designators; is this true? if 'yes' then the only letters will always be S and E, yes? can we also assume the 2 letters will already be capitalized?

No, these are just mixed strings examples for a possible use case.

In shell just something along:
while IFS=SE read -r _ a b; do
  printf "S%03dE%03d\n" "$a" "$b"
done <input


A naïve solution with two passes:

find longest sequence of digits
pad all digit sequences to that length

For example, with Perl:
input=/path/to/my/input
output=/path/to/my/result

digits=$(perl -nE '
        for (/\d+/g) { $m=length if length>$m }
        END { say $m }
    ' "$input")

perl -pe 's/\d+/ sprintf "%0'$digits'd",$& /eg' "$input" >"$output"


if there are no digit sequences in the input, digits will be assigned the empty string and the format string becomes "%0d" which means "strip leading zeros" but it doesn't matter because there won't be any substitutions

Using any sed plus GNU column for -o and -R, this will zero-pad up to the longest series of digits in each non-digit separated segment which isn't what the OP asked for but may be adequate for their real needs:
$ sed 's/[^0-9]/ & /g' file | column -o$'\t' -tR0 | sed 's/ /0/g; s/\t//g'
S70E001
S75E010
S41E100
S53E011

For a generic solution that'll do exactly what the OP ask for:
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
S070E001
S075E010
S041E100
S053E011

but will also work for any length string of non-digits between digits, and any number of segments and will pad the separators with _ as well as the digits with 0s, we can use a 2-pass approach with GNU awk for the 4th arg to split():
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    fldPadChar = "0"
    sepPadChar = "_"
}
{ numFlds = split($0, flds, /[^0-9]+/, seps) }
NR == FNR {
    for ( i=1; i<=numFlds; i++ ) {
        fw = length(flds[i])
        sw = length(seps[i])

        if ( fw > fldWids[i] ) {
            fldWids[i] = fw
            if ( fw > maxFldWid ) { maxFldWid  = fw }
        }
        if ( sw > sepWids[i] ) { sepWids[i] = sw }
    }
    if ( numFlds > maxNumFlds ) { maxNumFlds = numFlds }
    next
}
{
    for ( i=1; i<=maxNumFlds; i++ ) {
        # If never a field before the first separator or never a field after
        # the last separator then dont pad the empty string in that field.
        fw = ( ((i == 1) || (i == maxNumFlds)) && (fldWids[i] == 0) ? 0 : maxFldWid )
        fld = sprintf("%*s", fw, flds[i])
        sep = sprintf("%*s", sepWids[i], seps[i])
        printf "%s%s", gensub(" ",fldPadChar,"g",fld), gensub(" ",sepPadChar,"g",sep)
    }
    print ""
}

e.g. using more comprehensive sample input files:
$ cat file1
S70E1
S715E10X1234
ABC2DEFGH123
S41E100
ST537E11223344


$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file1
__S00000070____E00000001_00000000
__S00000715____E00000010X00001234
ABC00000002DEFGH00000123_00000000
__S00000041____E00000100_00000000
_ST00000537____E11223344_00000000


$ cat file2
122S70E1XYZ4PQR
S715E10X1234
ABC2DEFGH123
S41E100
ST537E11223344


$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file2
00000122__S00000070____E00000001XYZ00000004PQR
00000000__S00000715____E00000010__X00001234___
00000000ABC00000002DEFGH00000123___00000000___
00000000__S00000041____E00000100___00000000___
00000000_ST00000537____E11223344___00000000___

The fldPadChar and sepPadChar characters just cannot be & as that's a backreference metacharacter in gensub().

Interesting. I never thought string padding is a thing. But this generalization is helpful for making the whole sequence tabular. Thank you.

You're welcome. String padding is definitely a thing, usually done with blanks, e.g. try printf '%*s\n' 10 foo.

@EdMorton : instead of fldWids[i] = ( fw > fldWids[i] ? fw : fldWids[i] ) redefining it every row (esp when it's no change), perhaps something like ::::::::: ::::::: ::::::::::  :::::::: fw <= fldWids[i] || fldWids[i] = fw :::::  I used || instead of && by assuming no higher max value is the more likely scenario

Clarity over brevity and optimize-when-necessary. Given 10 million lines of random input as generated by shuf -i 1-10000000 > file10m the timing results are time awk '{x=(x > $1 ? x : $1)}' file10m outputs  real    0m1.728s user    0m1.640s sys     0m0.031s versus time awk '{$1 <= x || x = $1}' file10m outputs real    0m1.559s user    0m1.500s sys     0m0.000s, i.e. the difference is a fraction of a second so it's not worth replacing a clear, simple ternary with code that makes you wonder where the if is and would give a warning message if run with --lint.

If I did care about optimizing it for speed then I'd use the even faster if (fw > fldWids[i]) fldWids[i] = fw since time awk '{if ($1 <= x) x = $1}' file10m outputs real    0m1.407s user    0m1.328s sys     0m0.015s. In fact, while I don't care about the execution speed difference, I just updated my answer to use that where appropriate since it's a bit clearer than a ternary. Thanks for getting me thinking about it.

Given:
$ cat file
E15X12
E1S70
E10S75
E100S41
E11S53
C85X22

You can get what you are describing with the non POSIX sort extension of sort -V for a version sort. It can be surprising what you get out of this, since floats, signs and true decimals are not supported.
If you want predictability, or support POSIX sort, you can do something along these lines:
awk '{
        s=$0
        ss=""
        while (match(s, /[0-9]+|[^0-9]+/)) {
            sss=substr(s,1,RLENGTH)
            if (sss~/[0-9]+/)
                sss=sprintf("%015i",sss)
            ss=ss sss
            s=substr(s,RLENGTH+1,length(s))
        }
        printf "%s\t%s\n", ss,$0
}
' file | sort -k1 

Prints:
C000000000000085X000000000000022    C85X22
E000000000000001S000000000000070    E1S70
E000000000000010S000000000000075    E10S75
E000000000000011S000000000000053    E11S53
E000000000000015X000000000000012    E15X12
E000000000000100S000000000000041    E100S41

This uses a Decorate, Sort, Undecorate idiom to add a column with the digits zero padded so that sort is not confused by lexicographical vs numeric issues.
Then add | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} {print $NF}' to that pipe to undecorated the sort field.
If you have something more complicated, such as floats or signs, you are probably best served using Ruby, Python, Perl or their ilk to do a Natural Sort.
Here is a Ruby for this:
ruby -e 'puts $<.read.split(/\R+/).
    map{|s| 
        [s.split(/([+-]?(?:\d+\.?\d*)|(?:\d*\.\d+))/).
            map{|e| Float(e) rescue e}, s]
}.sort_by{|l| l[0]}.map(&:last)
' file

